# Services in AngularJS with YoutubeAPI v3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube-api

I've used services once before (still not very good at it) and I've encountered a lot of issues already, so know I'm going to ask (I think my problem is easy AF:) )

I need to get some ChannelDetails with the use of YoutubeApi v3.

My Service:

```
appApi.factory('ServiceAPI', ['$http', function($http) {

var factory = {};

    factory.channelDetails = function(channelname){
        return $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername='+channelname+'&key=AIzaSyDQv-WpATIWLinCB3H_sH4W1sKx7plyvRA')
         .success(function(data) {
           return data;
         })
         .error(function(data) {
           return data;
         });
         }
}]);
```

then my controller:

```
var appApi = angular.module('YoutubeAPI', ['ngRoute'])

appApi.controller('youtubeCTRL', ['$scope','$http','$q','ServiceAPI', function ($scope, $http, $q, ServiceAPI) {
    $scope.channel = [];

    //GET Id on channelname
    $scope.saveNewchlName = function () {

        var channelname = $scope.newchlName;

        $scope.channelDetails = function(channelname){

            ServiceAPI.channelDetails(channelname).success(function (data) {

                $scope.newchannelNames = {
                    channelName: $scope.newchlName,
                    channelId: data.items[0].id,
                    playlistId: data.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads
                };
                console.log($scope.newchannelNames)
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/resources/channelNames/',
                    data: $scope.newchannelNames,
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.channel.push(data);
                    console.log('SUCCESS!');
                    $scope.error = null;
                }).error(function (data, status) {
                    if (status == 401) {
                        $scope.error = "You are not authenticated to Post these data";
                        return;
                    }
                    $scope.error = data;
                });
    });
    }
}
```

My problem is that I keep encounter problems with injection. Now I got one which says: Provider 'ServiceAPI' must return a value from $get factory method.

I need to implement the channelname within the URL to get the specific details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work.

Service:

```
    appApi.factory('ServiceAPI', ['$http', function($http) {

    var factory = {};

        factory.channelDetails = function(channelname, success, error){
            var promise = $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername='+channelname+'&key=AIzaSyDQv-WpATIWLinCB3H_sH4W1sKx7plyvRA')
             if(success){
               promise.success(success);
             }
             if(error){
               promise.error(error);
             };
             }
             return factory;
    }]);
```

controller:

```
var appApi = angular.module('YoutubeAPI', ['ngRoute'])

appApi.controller('youtubeCTRL', ['$scope','$http','$q','ServiceAPI', function ($scope, $http, $q, ServiceAPI) {
    $scope.channel = [];
    $scope.video = [];


    var pagetokenarr = [];

    //GET Id on channelname
        $scope.saveNewchlName = function () {

            var channelname = $scope.newchlName;

                ServiceAPI.channelDetails(channelname, function(data){

                    $scope.newchannelNames = {
                        channelName: $scope.newchlName,
                        channelId: data.items[0].id,
                        playlistId: data.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads
                    };
                    console.log($scope.newchannelNames)
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/resources/channelNames/',
                        data: $scope.newchannelNames,
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }).success(function (data) {
                        $scope.channel.push(data);
                        console.log('SUCCESS!');
                        $scope.error = null;
                    }).error(function (data, status) {
                        if (status == 401) {
                            $scope.error = "You are not authenticated to Post these data";
                            return;
                        }
                        $scope.error = data;
                    });


        });
    }
```